# Onchange delete value from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add selected value only once (not o1-o2) into the variable as string, onchange, delete old value + add new selected value into string.

```js
$("#hotelVel").on("change", function() {
  let size = $("#hotelVel :selected").val();
  kod = kod + size;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="float:right;" name="first" id="hotelVel">
  <option value="-o1" name="velikost">Single room (10m²)</option>
  <option value="-o2" name="velikost">Double room (15m²)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is: `kod`?

Comment: It is variable that stores values as strings. In previous page it added "z5" into variable. Now i want to add -o1 or -o2 to it (...-o6), but my function adds them up like "z5-o1-o2" instead of "z5-o2" or "z5-o1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can empty your variable before join.

```js
let kod = 'z5';
$("#hotelVel").on("change", function() {
  let size = '';
  //kod = kod + size;
  size = $("#hotelVel :selected").val()
  kod = kod.split('-')[0] + size;
  console.log(kod);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="float:right;" name="first" id="hotelVel">
  <option value="-o1" name="velikost">Single room (10m²)</option>
  <option value="-o2" name="velikost">Double room (15m²)</option>
  <option value="-o3" name="velikost">Double room (20m²)</option>
  <option value="-o4" name="velikost">Double room (25m²)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have to leave kod untact. i have string inside "kod" that cant be deleted.

Comment: 'My string' is "z5", i want to kod = "z5-o1" if user selects -o1 and "z5-o2" if user selects -o2.. (...-o6)

Comment: See snippet for desire result.

Comment: z5 is inside global variable "kod" and i cant delete its content.

Answer (score 1):

make kod empty on function call. Use substring to remove the extra values on every call

```js
var kod='string'
$("#hotelVel").on("change", function() {
let size = $("#hotelVel :selected").val()
var aux=kod;
kod =aux+size;
console.log(kod)

kod=aux;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="float:right;" name="first" id="hotelVel">
     <option value="-o1" name="velikost">Single room (10m²)</option>
     <option value="-o2" name="velikost">Double room (15m²)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I need to leave kod untact, and i will add up more strings into kod variable.

Answer (score 0):

First you can simplify $("#hotelVel :selected").val() to $("#hotelVel").val().
I assume `kod` contains all options for the room right? in this case i would just see if the other option is already in the string:

```
$("#hotelVel").on("change", function() {
let size = $("#hotelVel").val();
let roomOptionsArr = kod.split("-");
let options = $(this).find("option").val();
let check = "";
for(let i = 0; i < roomOptionsArr.length; i++){
    if(options.includes("-" + roomOptionsArr[i])){
        check = "-" + roomOptionsArr[i];
        break;
    }
}
kod = kod.replace(check, "");
kod += size; // I simplified kod = kod + size by using += that appends automatically
});
```

Comment: This should work, however it adds up. (-o1-o2) I want to delete "o1" if user selects o2. What if i have -o1, -o2......-o6?

Comment: Ok you have more than 2 room sizes, I'll edit my answer

Comment: @Zyonix What I'm doing now is first getting all options from the roomstring with the - and then i go through tall of them and check if they appear in the option values of your select. if so, this string is saved in check and afterwards "-" + check is removed from the kod string. and your original size is added. this should do the trick (if there are no syntax error ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```js
$('#hotelVel').change(function(){
  let kod ='This is My String :';
  kod = kod+$(this).val();
  console.log(kod);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="float:right;" name="first" id="hotelVel">
     <option value="-o1" name="velikost">Single room (10m²)</option>
     <option value="-o2" name="velikost">Double room (15m²)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary variable to store selected value and compare it while updating `kod` as below.

```js
let kod = 'My string';
let hotelValue = '';

$("#hotelVel").on("change", function() {
  if (hotelValue != '' && kod.includes(hotelValue)) {
    kod = kod.replace(hotelValue, '');
  }
  hotelValue = $("#hotelVel :selected").val();
  kod = kod + hotelValue;
  console.log(kod);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="float:right;" name="first" id="hotelVel">
  <option value="-o1" name="velikost">Single room (10m²)</option>
  <option value="-o2" name="velikost">Double room (15m²)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Just Target `<select>`

When extracting the value from a `<select>` you simply need to either apply the JavaScript property `.value`:

> ```
>  let size = document.querySelector('#hotelVel').value
> ```

**or** the jQuery method `.val()` directly to the `<select>`, there's no need to mess around with the `<option>`s:

> ```
>   let size = $(this).val();
> ```

---

### Demo

```js
$("#hotelVel").on("change", function() {
  let size = $(this).val();
  let kod = 'z5' + size;
  console.log(kod);
});
```

```html
<select style="float:right;" name="first" id="hotelVel">
  <option value="-o1" name="velikost">Single room (10m²)</option>
  <option value="-o2" name="velikost">Double room (15m²)</option>
</select>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is strange. Your code works as i want it to, but if i copy it to my project, doesnt.

Comment: Your project has jQuery loaded? It's so basic that the only way it'd fail is if there's no jQuery loaded or a mismatch on the selector...other than that...IDK 

Comment: Yeah, at bottom of page. Kod is global variable that stores values as strings. In previous page it added "z5" or "z6". So i changed   "let kod = 'z5' + size; " into   kod += size; and the problem persists. instead of z5-o1 it adds up, (z5-o1-o2...)

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any nested elements within the select other than options and also check if any options have anything nested within them. Change `$('#hotelVel')` to `$('select')`.